# Compare slopes of mixed model regressions across three groups, controling for two random factors

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have repeated a quantile correlation test across taxonomic groups and also across different databases. Now, I'd like to know if  the correlations for the different quantiles rendered me sistematically different effect sizes, but keeping the comparisons within database and taxon.

For that, I executed the following code. I am unsure whether I coded it well and if my interpretation is correct.

```
  s=lmer(Slope~percentile +(1|Database)+(1|Taxon), data=df1)
  summary(s)

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.4235 -0.2702  0.0173  0.3187  3.9481 

Random effects:
 Groups         Name      Variance Std.Dev.
 Taxon        (Intercept) 0.08717  0.2952  
 Database     (Intercept) 3.47890  1.8652  
 Residual                 0.13591  0.3687  
Number of obs: 117, groups:  Group, 13; Tmax, 5

Fixed effects:
               Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)     1.40061    0.84699   1.654
percentile50th  0.11522    0.08348   1.380
percentile90th  0.40480    0.08348   4.849

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) prcn50
percntl50th -0.049       
percntl90th -0.049  0.500
```

My interpretation would be that, in general, the 90th percentile leads to a greater slope and a greater difference from percentile 10 (the reference level) than percentile 50th. Second, Database  had a stronger effect on the comparisons than taxon (I am unsure if it means that comparisons across percentiles were more  variable or had more sistematic effects across different databases, or if something else).

Finally, apart from the slopes, I also have the standard error for the initial percentile correlations, could/ should I use them in this posterior test? If yes, how could that be done? (ex. dividing the slope by the standard error and comparing them instead?)

Comment: Can you explain what a quantile correlation test is?

Comment: Sorry, Erik, that would take a whole stats class and i am far from being the best for that. The point here is to compare regression slopes in an aposteriori test, using a mixed models approach.

Comment: Ok. What do the residuals from this model look like? Are they approximately normally distributed? You can use `lattice::qqmath(model)` to check. The points should fall along the diagonal line That would help to know whether a linear model is appropriate for your outcome.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think is it well coded for the given question? using the stardard errors of the compared slopes would help in some manner?

Comment: I'm not sure how you would incorporate standard errors. You mention wanting within-database and within-taxons comparisons. I don't think you have that right now. To get it, you'd need to calculate means for the 50th and 90th percentiles by database and by taxon and then include those means as fixed effects predictors. Then your lower-level percentile effects are truly within- rather than a mixture of within- and between-groups.

Comment: Alternatively, you could treat taxon and database as fixed factors, and estimate an OLS model: `s1=lm(Slope~percentile + as.factor(Database) + as.factor(Taxon), data=df1)`. The coefficients for the 50th and 90th percentile should be exactly the same as the mixed model if you add the taxon and database means, as I described above.